# What are the best image sizes for the Google Chrome mobile website audit?

Tags: wordpress, images, optimization, image-size

What are the best image sizes for the Google Chrome mobile website audit?

I'm making a WordPress website and want to get the best score possible. There will be an image with 100% width on the top page. I just need to find out what sizes Google wants it to be now.

```
add_image_size( 'iphone-320', '320', '9999', false );
```

I'm going to add some code like this to the functions.php file of the template.

Answer (score 1):

PageSpeed Insights for example isn’t using “real devices” with resolutions.

Also see this post: [What is the screen size used by Google's PageSpeed Insights for mobile previews?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52349/what-is-the-screen-size-used-by-googles-pagespeed-insights-for-mobile-previews)

I would suggest using image sizes near your css breakpoints (assuming you have a responsive design).